# Find questions with multiple tags (AND, not OR)

Tags: tags, dataexplorer

How can I find questions that are tagged with multiple tags, for example, BOTH [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) AND [python](/questions/tagged/python)?

I've found answers on meta about using the browser to search multiple tags, but this question is specific to the SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com

In the table `Posts`, the column `Tags` are stored as ncharv(250) and tags are appended to the string (not stored as array). In the browser, it looks like this

[image]

I only need the question (and answer) text for some text mining, so I had tried going direct to the `Posts` table:

*pseudo_sql*

- select * from Posts where Tags in (tag_list)

> this returns tag1 **OR** tag2

- select * from Posts p1 inner join Posts p2 ON p1.Tags in (tag1) AND p2.Tags in (tag2)

I've also tried a larger query based on [this popular query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple tags, one **inefficient** way to use SEDE is multiple `LIKE` statements

```
SELECT TOP 10 
 * 
FROM Posts
WHERE Tags LIKE ('%python%')
AND Tags LIKE ('%regex%')
```

This will get you also similar tags, for example, [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

To get only those tags and no fuzzy matching, use

```
%<python>%
```

[permalink](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1056234/get-pythonregex-questions-with-non-regex-answers)